# Proof of limit of a piecewise function, rational, irrational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Prove that:

If $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$ and $f(x) = 1$ for rational $x$ then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does not exist for any $a$.

So begin by the opposite assumption:

Assume $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$, hence:

$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x - a| < \delta$

I think the way is by sided-limits.

$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $x-a < \delta_1$

$|f(x) - M| < \epsilon$ for $a- x < \delta_2$

We have to prove $M \ne L$ Obviously, start with the assumption $M = L$

lets take (1):

$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x-a| < \delta$

$|f(x) - L| = |f(x) - L + M - M| = |f(x) - M -(L - M)|$

Then:

$|f(x) - M| - |L - M| <|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x-a| < \delta$

Since $L = M$ we have: $L - M = 0$

Therefore,

$|f(x) - M| < |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x-a| < \delta$

But because $M = L$

$|f(x) - M| = |f(x) - L|$ must suffice.

A contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Is the proof accurate/

Comment: Replace f(x) = ... whatever with f(x) = 3 (which *is* continuous).  Does your proof change at all? You claim |f(x) - M| - |L -M| < |f(x) -L|.  Plug in f(x) = 3, M = 1, L = 2.  You get |3 - 1| -|1 - 2| < |3 - 2|.  Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

I think the fundamental issue here is your *understanding of non-existence of limit*.

You seem to assume that *the only way a limit does not exist is when both one-sided limits are unequal*. In reality, *this is one of the ways in which a limit may fail to exist*.

In fact for this question *even the one-sided limits also don't exist* and hence there is no question of their equality (or inequality).

The way to show non-existence of a limit here is to show that given any number $L$ and we can find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ does not hold for any number $\delta > 0$ and $0 < |x - a| < \delta$. The idea is know that if we have $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ then we have both rational and irrational $x$ satisfying this inequality. For rational $x$ we have $f(x) = 1$ and for irrational $x$ we have $f(x) = 0$ so that the expression $|f(x) - L|$ is either $|L|$ or $|L - 1|$. Now we can choose $0 < \epsilon < \min(|L|, |L - 1|)$ and the expression $|f(x) - L|$ is greater than $\epsilon$ no matter what $\delta$ you choose.

I have another feeling looking at your proof that you seem to have lost in the symbol manipulation game. Showing that a limit exists or does not exist is not just about manipulating some symbols like $\epsilon, \delta$. Rather you have to understand the meaning of those symbols in your natural language.

You start with *assume that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$. Hence $$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$ for $|x - a| < \delta$*.

Sorry!! this is not at all true. Assuming that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ means that **given any positive number $\epsilon$ we can choose a positive number $\delta$ such that $$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$ holds whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.** Hence *if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ does not exist* then it means that **whatever number $L$ we take, we can find a positive $\epsilon$ such that it is impossible to find a positive $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$.**

Unless you understand the meaning of the statements in bold in last paragraph completely I think it will be very difficult to come out of the symbol manipulation game.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is wrong for obvious reason that you never used the definition of function that $f$ is $1$ for rationals and $0$ for irrationals. The reader would be confused for introducing L and M and claiming they are equal and proving they are unequal. In particular, in the step

$|f(x) - M| - |L - M| <|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ for $|x-a| < \delta$

The first $<$ should be $=$

The classical proof of $f$ to be discontinuous makes use of the fact that any neighbourhood of a given point contains both rationals and irrationals.

Comment: I used the triangle inequality for the first one.

Comment: Triangle inequality : $\vert a+b\vert \leq \vert a \vert + \vert b \vert$

Comment: The triangle inequality for negative $|a - b|$

Comment: can you please post the entire inequality you are using

Comment: $|a| - |b| < |a - b|$

Comment: Its wrong! take a=1 and b=0

Comment: I meant $|a| - |b| \le |a - b|$

Comment: Yes! So, shouldn't your $<$ in the step mentioned be $\leq$ and then you would not have any contradiction at the end. You will just weaken $=$ to $\leq$

Comment: I see. Thanks, Ill figure something else out.

Comment: You haven't used *any* aspect about f.  Whatever you prove will be true for all functions unless you somehow use the definition of f.